# How to reaggregate a MultiIndex pandas.DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, multi-index

I have a MultiIndex pandas.DataFrame `dcba` with a large level of spatial desagregation:

```
region                            FR                                          \
sector                   Agriculture    Crude coal     Crude oil Natural gas   
region          stressor                                                       
FR              CO2         4.796711  1.382087e-02  3.149139e-05    2.894532   
                CH4        15.816831  3.744709e-05  3.567591e-04    0.275431   
                N2O         9.715682  9.290865e-05  5.603963e-07    0.007834   
                SF6         0.028011  2.818101e-06  2.607044e-08    0.000477   
                HFC         1.487352  1.473641e-04  1.475096e-06    0.024675   
...                              ...           ...           ...         ...   
RoW Middle East CH4         0.455748  3.566337e-05  7.060048e-04    0.035420   
                N2O         0.193417  1.176733e-06  7.366779e-07    0.002564   
                SF6         0.001478  7.465562e-08  2.960808e-08    0.000107   
                HFC         0.006629  3.190865e-07  1.281020e-07    0.000472   
                PFC         0.001390  1.491053e-07  3.205249e-08    0.000603   

region                                                                   \
sector                   Extractive industry Biomass_industry  Clothing   
region          stressor                                                  
FR              CO2             5.817926e-03         9.866832  0.394570   
                CH4             3.622520e-04         9.923741  0.075845   
                N2O             1.267742e-04         6.010542  0.027877   
                SF6             4.797571e-04         0.036355  0.000561   
                HFC             2.502868e-02         1.894707  0.028297   
...                                      ...              ...       ...   
RoW Middle East CH4             1.844972e-04         0.419346  0.193006   
                N2O             7.236885e-06         0.062690  0.018240   
                SF6             9.461463e-07         0.001052  0.000477   
                HFC             4.114220e-06         0.004652  0.002087   
                PFC             1.314401e-06         0.002939  0.001726   

region                                                           ...  \
sector                   Heavy_industry Construction Automobile  ...   
region          stressor                                         ...   
FR              CO2           13.261457    14.029825   2.479608  ...   
                CH4            0.632317     2.537475   0.319671  ...   
                N2O            0.196020     0.968326   0.082451  ...   
                SF6            0.024654     0.054173   0.003670  ...   
                HFC            1.641677     2.874809   0.197846  ...   
...                                 ...          ...        ...  ...   
RoW Middle East CH4            0.677210     0.926126   0.325147  ...   
                N2O            0.049768     0.034912   0.020158  ...   
                SF6            0.002112     0.001568   0.000955  ...   
                HFC            0.009280     0.006824   0.004142  ...   
                PFC            0.011609     0.006201   0.003916  ...   

region                   RoW Middle East                          \
sector                    Heavy_industry Construction Automobile   
region          stressor                                           
FR              CO2             0.580714     0.382980   0.162650   
                CH4             0.046371     0.114092   0.021962   
                N2O             0.019406     0.059560   0.007892   
                SF6             0.001126     0.000872   0.000270   
                HFC             0.073273     0.049812   0.015326   
...                                  ...          ...        ...   
RoW Middle East CH4             2.238149    19.760153   1.079266   
                N2O             0.222995     2.752258   0.069067   
                SF6             0.009341     0.162138   0.004313   
                HFC             0.041137     0.702098   0.018245   
                PFC             0.057405     0.285898   0.007766   

region                                                                  \
sector                   Oth transport equipment Machinery Electronics   
region          stressor                                                 
FR              CO2                     0.116935  0.394273    0.080354   
                CH4                     0.016530  0.048727    0.010756   
                N2O                     0.004032  0.018393    0.004233   
                SF6                     0.000166  0.000665    0.000115   
                HFC                     0.008293  0.036774    0.006075   
...                                          ...       ...         ...   
RoW Middle East CH4                     0.139413  3.370381    0.650511   
                N2O                     0.009559  0.247341    0.058345   
                SF6                     0.000506  0.013730    0.003265   
                HFC                     0.002176  0.056321    0.013685   
                PFC                     0.001429  0.030418    0.006383   

region                                                                         \
sector                   Fossil fuels Electricity and heat Transport services   
region          stressor                                                        
FR              CO2          0.107540             0.015568           0.058673   
                CH4          0.018198             0.003783           0.007705   
                N2O          0.006238             0.001653           0.003543   
                SF6          0.000204             0.000029           0.000061   
                HFC          0.010712             0.001534           0.003187   
...                               ...                  ...                ...   
RoW Middle East CH4         16.407198             5.020937           2.359744   
                N2O          0.134513             0.432547           0.510101   
                SF6          0.009963             0.007036           0.012166   
                HFC          0.044495             0.031509           0.051611   
                PFC          0.008458             0.004833           0.006725   

region                                
sector                     Composite  
region          stressor              
FR              CO2         0.801035  
                CH4         0.311628  
                N2O         0.150162  
                SF6         0.001836  
                HFC         0.094331  
...                              ...  
RoW Middle East CH4       119.001176  
                N2O         8.039872  
                SF6         0.941479  
                HFC         3.943134  
                PFC         0.422255  

[294 rows x 833 columns]
```

the desagregation is defined by the list of the regions.

```
reg_list = ['FR', 'Austria', 'Belgium', 'Bulgaria', 'Cyprus', 'Czech Republic', 'Germany', 'Denmark', 'Estonia', 'Spain', 'Finland', 'Greece', 'Croatia', 'Hungary', 'Ireland', 'Italy', 'Lithuania', 'Luxembourg', 'Latvia', 'Malta', 'Netherlands', 'Poland', 'Portugal', 'Romania', 'Sweden', 'Slovenia', 'Slovakia', 'United Kingdom', 'United States', 'Japan', 'China', 'Canada', 'South Korea', 'Brazil', 'India', 'Mexico', 'Russia', 'Australia', 'Switzerland', 'Turkey', 'Taiwan', 'Norway', 'Indonesia', 'South Africa', 'RoW Asia and Pacific', 'RoW America', 'RoW Europe', 'RoW Africa', 'RoW Middle East']

sectors_list = ['Agriculture', 'Crude coal', 'Crude oil', 'Natural gas', 'Extractive industry', 'Biomass_industry', 'Clothing', 'Heavy_industry', 'Construction', 'Automobile', 'Oth transport equipment', 'Machinery', 'Electronics', 'Fossil fuels', 'Electricity and heat', 'Transport services', 'Composite']
```

The Dataframe `dcba` has the following index and columns :

```
dcba.index =
MultiIndex([(             'FR', 'CO2'),
            (             'FR', 'CH4'),
            (             'FR', 'N2O'),
            (             'FR', 'SF6'),
            (             'FR', 'HFC'),
            (             'FR', 'PFC'),
            (        'Austria', 'CO2'),
            (        'Austria', 'CH4'),
            (        'Austria', 'N2O'),
            (        'Austria', 'SF6'),
            ...
            (     'RoW Africa', 'N2O'),
            (     'RoW Africa', 'SF6'),
            (     'RoW Africa', 'HFC'),
            (     'RoW Africa', 'PFC'),
            ('RoW Middle East', 'CO2'),
            ('RoW Middle East', 'CH4'),
            ('RoW Middle East', 'N2O'),
            ('RoW Middle East', 'SF6'),
            ('RoW Middle East', 'HFC'),
            ('RoW Middle East', 'PFC')],
           names=['region', 'stressor'], length=294)

dcba.columns =
MultiIndex([(             'FR',             'Agriculture'),
            (             'FR',              'Crude coal'),
            (             'FR',               'Crude oil'),
            (             'FR',             'Natural gas'),
            (             'FR',     'Extractive industry'),
            (             'FR',        'Biomass_industry'),
            (             'FR',                'Clothing'),
            (             'FR',          'Heavy_industry'),
            (             'FR',            'Construction'),
            (             'FR',              'Automobile'),
            ...
            ('RoW Middle East',          'Heavy_industry'),
            ('RoW Middle East',            'Construction'),
            ('RoW Middle East',              'Automobile'),
            ('RoW Middle East', 'Oth transport equipment'),
            ('RoW Middle East',               'Machinery'),
            ('RoW Middle East',             'Electronics'),
            ('RoW Middle East',            'Fossil fuels'),
            ('RoW Middle East',    'Electricity and heat'),
            ('RoW Middle East',      'Transport services'),
            ('RoW Middle East',               'Composite')],
           names=['region', 'sector'], length=833)
```

And I would like to reaggreagte this DataFrame at a different level by grouping the regions diferently, defined here :

```
dict_reag = 
{'United Kingdom': ['United Kingdom'],
 'United States': ['United States'],
 'Asia and Row Europe': ['Japan',
  'India',
  'Russia',
  'Indonesia',
  'RoW Europe'],
 'Chinafrica': ['China', 'RoW Africa'],
 'Turkey and RoW America': ['Canada', 'Turkey', 'RoW America'],
 'Pacific and RoW Middle East': ['South Korea',
  'Australia',
  'Taiwan',
  'RoW Middle East'],
 'Brazil, Mexico and South Africa': ['Brazil', 'Mexico', 'South Africa'],
 'Switzerland and Norway': ['Switzerland', 'Norway'],
 'RoW Asia and Pacific': ['RoW Asia and Pacific'],
 'EU': ['Austria',
  'Belgium',
  'Bulgaria',
  'Cyprus',
  'Czech Republic',
  'Germany',
  'Denmark',
  'Estonia',
  'Spain',
  'Finland',
  'Greece',
  'Croatia',
  'Hungary',
  'Ireland',
  'Italy',
  'Lithuania',
  'Luxembourg',
  'Latvia',
  'Malta',
  'Netherlands',
  'Poland',
  'Portugal',
  'Romania',
  'Sweden',
  'Slovenia',
  'Slovakia'],
 'FR': ['FR']}
```

The reaggregation process would transform this 294x833 DataFrame into a 66x187 DataFrame. Note that the new reaggreagation DataFrame corresponds to a sum of the first set of subregions.

I created an empty DataFrame with the correct new level of aggregation :

```
ghg_list = ['CO2', 'CH4', 'N2O', 'SF6', 'HFC', 'PFC']

multi_reg = []
multi_sec = []
for reg in list(reag_matrix.columns[2:]) :
    for sec in sectors_list :
        multi_reg.append(reg)
        multi_sec.append(sec)
arrays = [multi_reg, multi_sec]
new_col = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names=('region', 'sector'))

multi_reg2 = []
multi_ghg = []
for reg in list(reag_matrix.columns[2:]) :
    for ghg in ghg_list :
        multi_reg2.append(reg)
        multi_ghg.append(ghg)
arrays2 = [multi_reg2, multi_ghg]
new_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays2, names=('region', 'stressor'))

new_dcba = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((len(ghg_list)*len(list(reag_matrix.columns[2:])),len(sectors_list)*len(list(reag_matrix.columns[2:])))),
                              index =new_index,columns = new_col)
```

where `reag_matrix.columns[2:]` corresponds to the new list of regions, as defined in `dict_reag` :

```
list(reag_matrix.columns[2:]) = ['FR', 'United Kingdom', 'United States', 'Asia and Row Europe', 'Chinafrica', 'Turkey and RoW America', 'Pacific and RoW Middle East', 'Brazil, Mexico and South Africa', 'Switzerland and Norway', 'RoW Asia and Pacific', 'EU']
```

I guess I could use the groupby function but I could not make it work without losing the sector desaggregation.

Otherwise, I intended to do it iteratively, but I have errors I do not understand. I first tried to copy the French block which will stay the same :

```
s1 = dcba.loc['FR','FR'].copy()
new_dcba.loc['FR','FR'] = s1
```

But this last line raises the error `"The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()"` although it does not seems to contain any boolean. What is my problem here ?

Also, to avoid this, I tried to use :

```
new_dcba.loc['FR','FR'].update(s1, overwrite=True)
```

But it does not change the values in `new_dcba`.

Finally, I tried to use `.values` but then a new error is raised :

```
new_dcba.loc['FR','FR'] = s1.values
```

`"Must have equal len keys and value when setting with an ndarray"`

So, I have two question :
Can you guess of a way to use `groupby` (and `.sum()`) for this ?
What is the issue raising the first error ?

Note that I have gone through https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#returning-a-view-versus-a-copy and could not find any explanation for my specific problem.

I wrote an MCVE here, and it happens to work at a reducted size (what is commented), but not at the actual size of the problem :

```
list_reg_mcve = reg_list #['FR', 'United States', 'United Kingdom']
list_reg_mcve_new = list_reg_reag_new #['FR','Other']
sectors_list_mcve = sectors_list #['Agriculture','Composite']
dict_mcve = dict_reag #{'FR':['FR'],'Other' : ['United States', 'United Kingdom']}

ghg_list_mcve = ['CO2', 'CH4', 'N2O', 'SF6', 'HFC', 'PFC'] #['CO2','CH4']

multi_reg = []
multi_sec = []
for reg in list_reg_mcve :
    for sec in sectors_list_mcve :
        multi_reg.append(reg)
        multi_sec.append(sec)
arrays = [multi_reg, multi_sec]
new_col = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names=('region', 'sector'))

multi_reg2 = []
multi_ghg = []
for reg in list_reg_mcve :
    for ghg in ghg_list_mcve :
        multi_reg2.append(reg)
        multi_ghg.append(ghg)
arrays2 = [multi_reg2, multi_ghg]
new_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays2, names=('region', 'stressor'))

dcba_mcve = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((len(ghg_list_mcve)*len(list_reg_mcve),
                                   len(sectors_list_mcve)*len(list_reg_mcve))),
                              index =new_index,columns = new_col)

multi_reg = []
multi_sec = []
for reg in list_reg_mcve_new :
    for sec in sectors_list_mcve :
        multi_reg.append(reg)
        multi_sec.append(sec)
arrays = [multi_reg, multi_sec]
new_col = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays, names=('region', 'sector'))

multi_reg2 = []
multi_ghg = []
for reg in list_reg_mcve_new :
    for ghg in ghg_list_mcve :
        multi_reg2.append(reg)
        multi_ghg.append(ghg)
arrays2 = [multi_reg2, multi_ghg]
new_index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays(arrays2, names=('region', 'stressor'))

dcba_mcve_new = pd.DataFrame(np.zeros((len(ghg_list_mcve)*len(list_reg_mcve_new),
                                   len(sectors_list_mcve)*len(list_reg_mcve_new))),
                              index =new_index,columns = new_col)
from random import randint
for col in dcba_mcve.columns:
    dcba_mcve[col]=dcba_mcve.apply(lambda x: randint(0,5), axis=1)


print(dcba_mcve)

for reg_export in dict_mcve :
    list_reg_agg_1 = dict_mcve[reg_export]
    for reg_import in dict_mcve :
        list_reg_agg_2 = dict_mcve[reg_import]
        s1=pd.DataFrame(np.zeros_like(dcba_mcve_new.loc['FR','FR']),index=dcba_mcve_new.loc['FR','FR'].index, columns = dcba_mcve_new.loc['FR','FR'].columns)
        for reg1 in list_reg_agg_1 :
            for reg2 in list_reg_agg_2 :
                #print(reg1,reg2)
                s1 += dcba_mcve.loc[reg1,reg2].copy()
                #print(s1)
        dcba_mcve_new.loc[reg_export,reg_import].update(s1)
dcba_mcve_new
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: My guess is that with ```new_dcba.loc['FR','FR'].update(s1, overwrite=True)``` I am modifying a copy and not in place, but the exact same line worked in the MCVE. How is that possible ?

Comment: I just modified my MCVE to give it the size of the actual problem, and it does not work. This probably means there is a threshold size above which pd.DataFrame.update is not changing in place but is changing a copy... How am I suppose to avoid this ?